# JavaFX JAR does not exist in JRE System Library on Mac

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

I have a MacBook Pro 2018. I installed Java a couple of months ago and the current version of Java that I have installed is 10.0.2. I tried to use `JavaFX` on eclipse but it gives an error (see images below). The `JAR` exists in the installed `JDK` library but eclipse is not able to recognize it. I've tried to configure the build path and modify the access rules to allow JavaFX to run. I even added the `JavaFX` `JAR` externally but it did not run.

[error screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SDgxT.png) [error screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bjWTb.jpg) [error screenshot 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aChU2.png) [error screenshot 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u5pW9.png)

Comment: Have you installed the [e(fx)clipse](http://www.eclipse.org/efxclipse/index.html) plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your project is set up for Java 10 source compliance. Select Project -> Properties from the menu, go to Java Compiler, and make sure the compiler compliance level is set to 10.

Answer (score 0):

When you select the JDK for your project or the default setting for Eclipse, make sure that you do not select an "Execution environment" but instead explicitly select an installed JDK. JavaFX is not part of an execution environment.